# When does malloc() set EAGAIN error?

Tags: c, malloc, solaris

I read the manual on `malloc()` in Solaris, and find that `malloc()` can set `EAGAIN` error in Solaris.

The manual writes:

> EAGAIN  There is not enough memory available to allocate size bytes of memory; but  the application could try again later.

Personally, I think if the `malloc()` returns `NULL`, there must be a memory leak or some other persistent problem. If that happens how would trying again later help?

So I want to know, in what conditions can `malloc()` set `EAGAIN` errno? Has anyone encountered such situation?

Comment: You stated the answer in your question. What are you actually asking? If there's no memory, there's no memory. Either you app used it all, or another app.

Comment: @Dariusz: Yeap, then what's the purpose of `EAGAIN`?

Comment: *"I think if the malloc() returns NULL, there must be a memory leak"* You are wrong. It isn't feasible for an operating system to detect memory leaks. That's why there are memory debuggers/profilers such as valgrind.

Comment: It seems `EAGAIN` would be given when other processes are hogging memory, while `ENOMEM` is only given on Solaris when you're mallocing beyond the physical limits of the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard `malloc()` does not set errno to `EAGAIN` on failure.

Under Unix, `malloc()` will most probably set errno to `ENOMEM`.

In general errno `EAGAIN` means `Resource temporarily unavailable`. Which means that the operating system may have the resource available in some time.

This is just a way of saying *right now I haven't enough memory, but I will try to free some in the nearest future and then I can give it to you*.

This may be related to the way operating systems usually allocate memory to processes - even if the memory is `free()'d` it does not return to the operating system, but is still reserved for that process.

*I am only speculating*, but perhaps in case of `EAGAIN` the system will try to reallocate the unused memory assigned to the other processes. This may take time, hence the `EAGAIN` return code.

I would suggest using `sleep()` after receiving `EAGAIN` and then trying it again. After the second call either memory will be allocated or another error returned. If it's `ENOMEM`, then the case is clear, there's no memory. If it's `EAGAIN` again... It's up to you.

Comment: 'Under Unix, malloc() will most probably set errno to ENOMEM.'
This is not true on Solaris and its decedents. If the OS is actually out of memory (RAM + swap), it will set errno to EAGAIN.

Comment: If malloc fails because the process exceeds its allowed memory limit as set by `setrlimit()`, then one would see ENOMEM.

Answer (score 0):

Standard malloc function doesn't set `errno` on failure. So it's only specific to the  [**implementation of malloc**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2243/malloc-3c/index.html) on Solaris that has this additional feature.
Note that malloc *still* returns NULL on failure.

So you can still check for return value of malloc() and not bother checking about `errno` which is the standard malloc's behaviour and should be enough on all occasions. Just that `errno` provides additional information about failure which may be helpful on certain occasions.

Generally speacking, checking `errno` makes sense only along with the return code. Relying `errno` may or may not indicate any failures.

Comment: This is all nice, but you haven't addressed the actual questions.

Comment: Just a note. UNIX98 standard requires malloc to set `errno` to `ENOMEM` in case of no memory. If you make a custom implementation you have to follow that rule.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It *does* address the question. `Why does malloc() set errno?` It's specific to the implementation. `in what conditions can malloc() set EAGAIN errno` OP answered it himself and manual says when.

Answer (score 0):

opengroup.org (POSIX) says:

> Upon successful completion with size not equal to 0, malloc() shall return a pointer to the allocated space. If size is 0, either a null pointer or a unique pointer that can be successfully passed to free() shall be returned. Otherwise, it shall return a null pointer [CX]   and set errno to indicate the error.
>
> ERRORS
>
> The malloc() function shall fail if:
>
> [ENOMEM]
>
> [CX]  Insufficient storage space is available.

[POSIX malloc description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html)

Solaris comes from a different UNIX family and you will encounter lots of differences between POSIX and base Solaris - i.e., The most glaring thing for new users is normally awk. Solaris has an ancient awk : /usr/bin/awk, /usr/xpg/bin/awk is more "modern", /usr/bin/nawk is what you use when porting shell scripts to Solaris.  These anachronisms come from way back and are there so old utilities and syscalls will remain functional on new versions of Solaris.